# JSON object's property value to list

Tags: javascript, json

How can we list the value for a property (e.g., "ObjectPropertyTwo") in the following JSON object array?

```
    {
    "KeyOne": [
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
    ],
    "KeyTwo": [
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
    ],
    "KeyThree": [
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        },
        {
            "ObjectPropertyOne": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyTwo": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyThree": "value",
            "ObjectPropertyFour": "value",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your edit was inappropriate and off-topic, and was rolled back properly - by a moderator. I am locking this to prevent further editing for now. When the lock expires, *do not* add back in your off-topic comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
for (var key in data) { //data being the object
    for (var i = 0; i < data[key].length; i++) {
        console.log(data[key][i].ObjectPropertyTwo);
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/csFms/

Comment: My apologies for my delay in response, I confirmed your answer solved the problem thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```javascript
function listNestedProperties(object, property) {
  return Object.keys(object).reduce(function(memo, key) {
    object[key].forEach(function(o2) {
      memo.push(o2.ObjectPropertyTwo);
    });
    return memo;
  }, []);
}

listNestedProperties(yourObject, 'ObjectPropertyTwo');
// => ["value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value", "value"]
```

Comment: Thanks @maerics, but this didn't work, http://jsfiddle.net/mrbilljsf/Pcrnz/2/.

Comment: @id.ot: oops, there was a typo; see the updated answer.